# Primers for human tissue?

Tags: human-genetics, pcr, primer

If I wanted to examine human tissue samples, such as hair, blood, fingernails, etc, for their DNA, what primers would I use for the amplification of the DNA when extracted(PCR)?

edit: To look at the STR in the human genome based off of the FBI's CODIS system http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combined_DNA_Index_System

from wikipedia:

"CODIS identifies genetic markers at 13 STR loci, plus Amelogenin (AMEL) to determine sex.

```
CSF1PO
D3S1358
D5S818
D7S820
D8S1179
D13S317
D16S539
D18S51
D21S11
FGA
THO1
TPOX
vWA
```

"

I read something about CODIS, but I don't know too much about it, if any one could give me some specifics that would be helpful.

Comment: The human genome is 3 billion letters long.  You aren't going to look at all of that, are you?  You have to know what you want to look at.  Are you just trying to examine the microsatillites that are used in DNA fingerprinting?

Comment: @swbarnes2      Sorry I was not thinking, I want to look at a microsatillite area, a subset i believe is called STR(single tandem repeats), since they have been used before in identification historically?

Comment: Saying that you want to look at the STR is still pretty broad.

Comment: @Chris          I guess I want to do the same type of identification that the FBI does with its CODIS system

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [References](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combined_DNA_Index_System#References) and [External Links](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combined_DNA_Index_System#External_links) sections of the Wikipedia article in your question contain a great deal of relevant information to get you started. There is a link to the FBI's CODIS and NDIS (National DNA Index System) Fact Sheet, which contains a lot of relevant information, including part numbers for validated kits from several manufacturers. DOI numbers for some journal articles are given in the Wikipedia article as well, wherein you may be able to find specific primer sequences or references for them. Finally, there is a link to the main CODIS page on FBI.gov, which contains an abundance of useful information, including the NDIS operational procedures manual.

You just need to look to find what you seek.

Answer (score 1):

Extracting genomic DNA and PCR are different processes. Extracting genomic DNA means that you get all the DNA sequences from human genome. Using extracted DNA, you can amplify a specific region from the whole genomic sequence.

A primer set is usually set at the both ends of a sequence you want to amplify the sequence. In your case, you the region highlighted in yellow in the figure "CODIS markers" of the wiki would be amplified.

Different people may set primers differently even if they want to amplify the same region; however, in this case, primer sequences are already determined to get consistent results. If you would like to know the actual sequences that FBI is using, you (or someone or I) have to search to find them.

Comment: By the way, some protocols may skip the extraction process--taking several micro litters of buffer-suspension of samples or something like this. It may depend on whether  the PCR enzyme can overcome inhibitory effects of crude DNA solutions to amplify fragments.